# snakemake - replacing dynamic() with checkpoints

Tags: snakemake

I have the following snakemake workflow:

```
rule all:
    input:
        dynamic(os.path.join(config['out_dir'],'{CHR}','{CHR}.fa'))
    output:
        config['out_dir'] + '/all.fasta'
    shell:
        """
        cat {input} > {output}
        """

rule split_genome_to_chr:
    """
    Split the input genome fasta to
    multiple fastas with one chromosome
    in each.
    """
    input:
        config['input_genome']
    output:
        dynamic(os.path.join(config['out_dir'],'{CHR}','{CHR}.fa'))
    params:
        out_dir=config['out_dir'],
    conda:
        CONDA_ENV_DIR + '/faSplit.yml'
    shell:
        """
        faSplit byname {input} {params.out_dir}/ -outDirDepth=1
        """
```

This works fine, but prints some warnings regarding the deprecation of dynamic() in favor of checkpoints.
I went through the checkpoints documentation, but still couldn't figure out how to change my code so it uses checkpoints instead of dynamic. Here's what I tried:

```
def aggregate_input(wildcards):
    return checkpoints.split_genome_to_chr.get(chrom=wildcards.CHR).output[0]  

rule all:
    input:
        aggregate_input
    output:
        config['out_dir'] + '/all.fasta'
    shell:
        """
        cat {input} > {output}
        """

checkpoint split_genome_to_chr:
    """
    Split the input genome fasta to
    multiple fastas with one chromosome
    in each.
    """
    input:
        config['input_genome']
    output:
        os.path.join(config['out_dir'],'{CHR}','{CHR}.fa')
    params:
        out_dir=config['out_dir'],
    conda:
        CONDA_ENV_DIR + '/faSplit.yml'
    shell:
        """
        faSplit byname {input} {params.out_dir}/ -outDirDepth=1
        """
```

but getting the error message:

```
InputFunctionException in line 51 of workflow.snakefile:
AttributeError: 'Wildcards' object has no attribute 'CHR'
Wildcards:
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Wildcards are defined at the level of a rule, by matching output file pattern with concrete file names that the rule is used to produce. Your rule `all` doesn't have a `{CHR}` in its output pattern, so there cannot be a `CHR` wildcard at the level of rule `all`.

Comment: Your checkpoint is apparently supposed to "Split the input genome fasta to multiple fastas with one chromosome in each.", but its output is a single file. I  suspect something wrong here. Shouldn't the output be a directory instead? Then you would `glob` in this directory in `aggregate_input` to determine actually existing fasta files.